# Formassembly remove padding

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I need to fix the alignment of an embedded iframe form assembly form into my Squarespace site.

The form assembly style has too much top and left padding and margin so the form is unable to embed inline with site style:

[Misaligned iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vUjD.png)

[Preferred alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U39g9.png)

I am able to get the desired effect by editing the css in the browser like below:

```
.wFormContainer .wForm form {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

   .wFormContainer .wForm {
  
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important; }

.wFormContainer .wFormHeader {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
```

However, when I try to make these changes in the form assembly custom code editor the changes do not reflect.

Can I make these changes on my Squarespace site?

Any tips are welcome.

The dev site can be viewed here https://www.thepush.com.au/freeza-2 Password is "showme"

Comment: the "!important" should be here. can you try?
.wFormContainer .wForm form {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

Comment: hello, thanks that is what I had in production but didn't copy it over, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wFormContainer .wForm form {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
  
.wFormContainer .oneField, .wFormContainer .section {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
  
.wFormContainer .actions .primaryAction {
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please "edit" to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 